# Is there any free WiFi network available at the boarding port in Montevideo for the Buquebus boat service between Montevideo and Buenos Aires?

Tags: sea-travel, wifi, buenos-aires, uruguay, montevideo

Is there any free Wi-Fi network available at the boarding port in Montevideo (Terminal de Buquebus Montevideo in Puerto de Montevideo) for the Buquebus boat service between Montevideo and Buenos Aires?

Comment: This question gets deleted again and again and again :(

Comment: Similar question was previously asked about the Buenos Aires port: [Is there any free WiFi network available at the boarding port in Buenos Aires (RENAPER Buquebus) for the Buquebus boat service?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/151745/is-there-any-free-wifi-network-available-at-the-boarding-port-in-buenos-aires-r?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://www.wifimap.io/4047-montevideo-free-wifi, there is a free wifi hotspot located in the same place as the Buquebus terminal:

[image]